# Make file having two main files

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I'm new to Makefile stuff and want to ask a question about Makefiles. Suppose I have two separate programs having their own .c .h and main.c files. None of the programs are linked. Is it possible to make two executables of such kind of program? If so, how is it possible? I have tried this but it failed, and I got the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your makefile you can have more than one target. For instance:

```
all: A B

A: mainA.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $^

B: mainB.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

Then `make A` would build A only, `make B` would build B only, and `make all` (or just `make`) would build both.

Answer (score 3):

If the two programs have a main.c file then you have to place them in two separate directories. Then, write a makefile in each directory and a makefile in the top directory that recurses into these two submakefiles.

```
/
  Makefile
  prog0/
    Makefile
    main.c
    ...
  prog1/
    Makefile
    main.c
    ...
```

prog0/Makefile would look like so:

```
all: prog0
prog0: prog0.o
    $(LINK.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $^
```

Repeat for prog1. Then, in the parent directory, write a recursive makefile:

```
all:
    $(MAKE) --directory prog0 all
    $(MAKE) --directory prog1 all
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your linker twice, to create two different programs.

Within a program, only one "main" can exist.  The problem likely stems from compiling two '.c' files (each containing a main) into two '.o' files and then attempting to create one executable out of both '.o' files.  The puzzle (which isn't allowed) to the compiler is "which main to start with"?

One quick way to fix this is to separate out the mains into respective 'mainXXX.c' files and then make sure that only one 'mainXXX.o' file is referenced per output executable.  Other solutions exist too.  Craft one that suits your needs.